# Custom JSON encode with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a PHP array looking like:

```
$columnDefs = array();

$column = new StdClass();
$column->target = array(0);
$column->orderable = false;
$column->searchable = false;
$column->render = 'function(id){
    return \'<input type="checkbox" value="\' + id + \'" />\';
}';

$columnDefs[] = $coluna;
```

I want to encode it with some kind of JSON to use it in JavaScript. The result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "target": [0],
        "orderable": false,
        "searchable": false,
        "render": function(id){
            return '<input type="checkbox" value="' + id + '" />';
        }
    }
]
```

The problem is the `json_encode()` PHP function is quoting the "render" field.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: No. You are assigning a string, so you are getting a string. `function() {...}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct, but I feel compelled to add that your example is a valid JavaScript Object. The distinction should be made that "JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format" that can be read and written by multiple languages. "It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent." (src: [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/))